# Слайдер на jQuery. Проблема с Fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Пишу простой слайдер на jQuery. Начал делать кнопки для перехода. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: если нажимать только кнопку **вперед**, все работает как надо, если нажимать только кнопку **назад**, все так же работает, как и задумывалось. Но если нажать, например, сначала **вперед**, а потом **назад**, или наоборот, текущий слайд резко исчезает и появляется снова, как будто это следующий слайд. Знаю, что напортачил где-то в логике (т.к. активному слайду в такой ситуации, почему-то, присваивается display: none), но я не знаю где именно. Прикладываю код ниже для полного воспроизведения проблемы

```js
function Slider(options) {
  this.img_arr = [].slice.call(options.content.find("img"));
  this.max_count = (this.img_arr.length - 1) * -1;
  var count = 0;
  this.img_arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    item.style.zIndex = count;
    count--;
  });
}

Slider.prototype.next = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.img_arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    if (item.style.zIndex == 0)
      $(item).css("zIndex", self.max_count)
    else if (item.style.zIndex != self.max_count)
      $(item).hide().fadeIn(1000).css("zIndex", parseInt(item.style.zIndex) + 1);
    else
      $(item).css("zIndex", parseInt(item.style.zIndex) + 1).hide();
  });
}

Slider.prototype.back = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.img_arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    if (item.style.zIndex == self.max_count)
      $(item).css("zIndex", 0).hide();
    else if (item.style.zIndex == 0)
      $(item).hide().fadeIn(1000).css("zIndex", parseInt(item.style.zIndex) - 1);
    else
      $(item).css("zIndex", parseInt(item.style.zIndex) - 1)
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #e2e1e0;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px
}
.slider-block {
  position: inherit;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2%;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
  top: 4rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru">
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <title>Slider.js - тестовое задание</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
 <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="slider-block" id="slider-content">
                <img src="http://best-wallpaper.net/wallpaper/1024x768/1105/Space-in-StarCraft-II_1024x768.jpg"/>
                <img src="http://ru.best-wallpaper.net/wallpaper/1024x768/1301/Pictures-of-beautiful-creative-design-forest-winter-planet-space_1024x768.jpg"/>
                <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Autumn-Tree-Background-1024x768.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a id="back_button">(-- </a>
        <a id="next_button"> --)</a>
 </body>
    <script>
        var slider = new Slider({
            'content': $('#slider-content')
        });

        document.querySelector('#next_button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            slider.next();
        });

        document.querySelector('#back_button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            slider.back();
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение. Код функции back  должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Slider.prototype.back = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.img_arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
        if(item.style.zIndex == self.max_count)
            $(item).hide().fadeIn(1000).css("zIndex", 0);
        else if(item.style.zIndex == 0)
            $(item).css("zIndex", parseInt(item.style.zIndex) - 1);
        else 
            $(item).css("zIndex", parseInt(item.style.zIndex) - 1).hide()
    });
}
```